# How to show the correct cell in a UICollectionView on changing device orientation?

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, device-orientation

I am making a Gallery, just like the photos app. I am using a UICollectionView to show images. These images can be both landscape and portrait. I'm setting the cell size as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  return collectionView.frame.size
}
```

Also I'm setting:

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

I am getting the behaviour as expected in both portrait and landscape orientations of the device.

The problem I am facing is when I change the orientation, wrong cell is displayed.

I tried changing the target offset using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
```

This did not work for me. How do I fix this?